# Eigenvectors of a matrix with complex entries

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to prove that if $\vec{z}$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $A$ with complex entries, then $\bar{\vec{z}}$ is an eigenvector of $\bar{A}$.

My approach: $A\vec{z}=\lambda\vec{z} \implies \bar{A}\bar{\vec{z}} = \overline{A\vec{z}} = \overline{\lambda\vec{z}} = \bar{\lambda}\bar{\vec{z}} $. From this, we can infer that $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $\bar{A}$. However, I'm afraid this does not prove that $\bar{\vec{z}}$ is an eigenvector of $\bar{A}$.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Why is it you think this is not adequate proof? What about it leads you to think that?

Comment: Ah yes, using "\overline" instead of "\bar" for extended arguments is much more clear; I was about to do something about his myself . . . Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I parse it, what is being said is, basically, that assuming we have $\vec z \ne 0$ with

$A\vec z = \lambda \vec z, \tag{1}$

then we may take complex conjugates and write

$\overline{A \vec z} = \overline{\lambda \vec z}; \tag{2}$

also,

$\overline{A \vec z} = \bar A \bar{\vec z} \tag{3}$

and

$\overline{\lambda \vec z} = \bar \lambda \bar{\vec z}; \tag{4}$

thus, since as Euclid might say, "things equal to equals are equal to each other" (i.e., in modern terms, the transitivity of the relation "$=$"), we indeed have

$\bar A \bar{\vec z} = \overline {A \vec z} = \overline{\lambda \vec z} = \bar \lambda \bar{\vec z}, \tag{5}$

that is,

$\bar A \bar{\vec z} = \bar \lambda \bar{\vec z}; \tag{6}$

since $\bar{\vec z} \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow \vec z \ne 0$, (6) shows that $\bar{\vec z}$ is an eigenvector of $\bar A$ with eigenvalue $\bar \lambda$.

Note that (3) and (4) hold as a simple extension of $\overline {a + b} = \bar a + \bar b$ and $\overline{ab} = \bar a \bar b$ for $a, b \in \Bbb C$.

If this is what our OP sequence intended, then his/her proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, but... Ax = λx does not imply that x is the eigenvector of A corresponding to λ. Or does it? Must be a gap in my knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: @sequence:  Ah, but it *does*!  That's the definition!  Provided of course that $x \ne 0$; that's why I took pains to say so about $\bar {\vec z}$!  So you were right all along!  Cheers!

Comment: Cool, thanks. I must've forgotten that from the very first course in linear algebra - I took it a good while ago.

Comment: @sequence:  my pleasure, glad to help out!